# Kubernetes dynamic ingress for multitenant application

Tags: laravel, kubernetes, multi-tenant, nginx-ingress

I'm have a multitenant SaaS application that I'm migrating to kubernetes from a VM infrastructure, in the application the client can connect his own domain by setting the cname we provide.

I'm trying to achieve that in kubernetes the steps I am thinking of is
1- create ingress yaml files and store them in PVC
2- trigger a job from my deployment
3- inside the job run kubectl apply on the ingress yaml files

is there a better approach? is it good practice to run k8s commands from inside my application?

Comment: from where do you want to write the ingress to the pvc? You could also deploy the ingress directly. Whats the purpose of this intermediate step?

Comment: Yes, I suppose I could deploy directly from my app container... Still how is this possible? And is it best practice?

Comment: Best practice questions are not really suited for stack overflow, since they are opinion based. So you want to create the ingress from your app as far as I understand. You could use a client library or kubectl or the rest api. Or you could do what you suggest.  Its all possible, for sure.